# Can't access data from DataBase ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have project only for my database. 
I want to have method that return all car bands. 
In database "Cars" table is: `id, carName.`
So, this is my helper for working with that table:

```
public class CarsHelper
{
    private ProjectEntities db;

    public CarsHelper()
    {
        db = new ProjectEntities();
    }

    public List<Car> List()
    {
        var car= db.Cars;
        return car.ToList();
    }
}
```

The problem is when I use `List` the result is 0, but I have data in table. Any sugestions?

I have reference for that project in main project.

Comment: can you post your `Car` class?

Comment: also instead of creating a variable to hold the `Cars` you can just return that in 1 line with `return db.Cars.ToList();`

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a web framework. It has nothing to do with data access. Did you mean *Entity Framework*? Are there any rows in the database? Are you connecting to the correct database?

Comment: please show us how are you passing the list to your controller and view

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `ConnectionString` is correct. you can also assign it in `CarHelper` constructor

```
public CarsHelper()
{
    db = new ProjectEntities();
    db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString ="Your Connection String";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code;

```
public List<Car> List()
{
   var car=(from data in db.Cars
            select data).ToList();
   return car;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Why did you think that will solve the problem?